# How to add dynamic links to Google and his bots

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a website which when you first go to the website it will just display the normal domain so /. When they use the form they will get forwarded to lets say /question/DYNAMIC(question id).

So google has no way to see these links.

Is there a way to tell google about all of these links without manually putting these in and without having to keep this up-to-date as some question might be removed at a later date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/)

Comment: yes, so i will have to manually add each link. O actually i could create this in a php file and the dynamicness in there.

Comment: Yep! That's how dynamic sites do it.

Comment: lol indeed, very peculiar that i didn't think of this :/ 4 years of back end and i miss this very very simple idea :O

Comment: you got a very easy correct answer and plus up, thanks a lot dude :)